# Smooth vertices with snapping

Tags: modeling, mesh, topology

I'm trying my first ever retopology of a high-poly triangle mesh to a low-poly quad mesh. I'm using a combination of of Bsurfaces and snap-to-face on my target mesh:

[image]

As a tidying step, I'd like to smooth the vertices of my new low-poly mesh. The "Smooth Vertex" tool doesn't honor the snap-to-face setting, so gives results like this:

[image]

Is there a tool that can smooth vertices, while staying snapped to the source mesh?

Comment: Maybe try Smooth modifier followed by one more Shrinkwrap modfier with a bit modified settings (so it doesn't get rid of all results of smoothing). But I'd say it's something to choose between - either create roughly original low poly mesh and keep the low poly count, or recreate it with smoothed surfaces (and more polys).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be easier for You to use Shrinkwrap modifier on the lower poly mesh and make high poly mesh its target. This way no matter what you do, vertices will stick to high poly mesh surface. I usually also check "keep above the surface" option and make Offset something higher then 0, but it's not crucial.